# How to wait in a thread until some data is available in another thread

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to add a TCP server to my application. My application generates some data time to time. I want to send the generated data to all clients connected to my server as soon as some new data is generated.

So far, I have created a `ServerSocket` in a separate thread which busy waits for client connections. When a new client is connected, a new thread is spawned for that `Socket`, which busy reads any data received from the `Socket`.

What I cant figure out is, how I can just wait in a per client spawned thread until some data is generated in my app. In current situation, the thread is stuck until some new data is arrived from the client because it busy waits for data from the client. I don't want to force my clients to send some data periodically to get any new data generated in my app. I want to send data as soon as they are genrated.

Comment: Object.wait/notify; CountDownLatch; ReentrantLock

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as waiting for data, think of it as waiting then being notified when there's data. You wait on a common lock object and the thread providing the data calls notifyAll() on the lock object and all threads waiting on it will be woken up.

Comment: Thanks for the information MadProgrammer and Bohemian. I am curious whether I can both wait for any data from data generating thread as well as any data from client simultaneously? So that I can send any data generated as soon as it is generated, as well as reply to any special request from client as soon as client requests?